# Unresolved reference BuildConfig.field

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, android-multi-module

I'm working on a multi-module project. In a module called **network** I'm providing the instance of Retrofit through Hilt dependency injection and works fine, I can compile the app, and run unit and instrumentation tests but when I try to execute all unit tests from the terminal as `.\gradlew test` then this error appears:

```
Unresolved reference: BASE_API_URL
```

Which is a key saved into **BuildConfig**

This is how looks like my **debug** build type:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled = false
        debuggable = true
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_API_URL", "\"https://gateway.marvel.com:443\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PUBLIC_API_KEY", "\"c3103d371d2sddd625sdsd4c9f12f0qq312dcbd5102165\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PRIVATE_API_KEY", "\"26121b5a8849ac897ace8d33a66a6f731ff7a93a\""
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debugTesting {
        minifyEnabled = false
        debuggable = true
        buildConfigField "String", "BASE_API_URL", "\"http://localhost:8080\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PUBLIC_API_KEY", "\"abcde\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PRIVATE_API_KEY", "\"abcd\""
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm retrieving the value:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}
```

Maybe some of you have faced this problem before and now know how to fix it. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the solution to the issue, it was due because in my multimodule project when I ran the tests like `.\gradlew test` the project was built based on `defaultConfig`. One workaround that I found was to put the `buildConfigField` in the  `defaultConfig` like:
[image]

But later I noticed that we can specify over which build variant build the project in order to execute the unit tests, finally, I got the following solution:

```
./gradlew testDebugUnitTest
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution. What imports and implementations did you use? Mine compiles like it knows the key, but keeps showing unresolved on '''BuildConfig.'''